# boosts buffer into char* (no std::string)

Tags: c++, boost, char, buffer

So, it may be sounds as a realy newbies question... And proboly it is newbies :)

I try to turn infomation from boost::asio::streambuf which I got, using `read_until` into char*. I've found realy many examples of turning it into std::string, but I'd mad, if use bufer -> std::string -> `c_str` in an application, needs a high perfomanse. (But in fact, I ectally do not realy stuff like conteiners and so on.)

Comment: There are two things... 

I'm a Russian realy young coder, so I may make few mistakes in English)...

And if my q. is two simle, just commnet like "read manuals lazy guy!", to let me know, my q. is not to strange to answer it...

Comment: Try using a different boost::asio read function. Use one of the overloads that stores the data directly into a char array instead of the streambuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that converting a std::string into a C string hurts performance.

This should not be assumed.  std::string is often implemented as a wrapper around a C string.

If you are unhappy with current performance, start by using a run-time profiler on your code.

Comment: M... Okay... Thanks...

I had seen only reading from stream, made by streambuf way of doing that (and it was realy slow), now I've found better ways of doing that. (through iterators)